# Converting a variable value into a variable name and accessing previously stored values

Tags: python, variables

I am currently trying to create some sort of simple recommendation system for customers at a liquor store. After answering a couple of simple questions via input() (type of alcohol e.g. wine, subtype e.g. shiraz, price):

```
class Customer(object):

    def __init__(self, alcohol, interest, budget, preference):
        self.alcohol = alcohol
        self.interest = interest
        self.budget = budget
        self.preference = preference

    # recording user input

    @classmethod
    def ask_customer(c):
        while True:

            # getting alcohol kind
            alcohol = input("What the customer would like to purchase?")
            if alcohol.lower() not in alcohol_types:
                print("Enter the right type of alcohol that we have in store")
                alcohol = input("> ")
            else:
                pass

            # getting the type of preferred alcohol
            interest = input(f"What type of {alcohol} is the customer is looking for?> ")
            if interest.lower() not in wine_types:
                print(f"Enter the right type of {alcohol}")
                interest = input("> ")
            else:
                pass

            # getting how much money the customer is willing to spend
            budget = input(f"How much is the customer willing to spend on a bottle of {interest}> ")
            if not budget.isdigit():
                print("Enter the number")
                budget = input("> ")
            else:
                pass

            # getting taste preferences of the customer
            preference = input(f"What style of {interest} is the customer looking for?")
            if preference.lower() not in preference_list:
                print(f"Enter a different description for {interest}")
                preference = input("> ")
            else:
                break
```

I then access a list of lists with the user's parameters:

```
     if interest == "shiraz":
            # get_wines to extract items from shiraz list that satisfy the taste and price requirements
            chosen_wines = []

            for sublist in shiraz_list:
                if sublist[1] == budget and sublist[2] == preference:
                    chosen_wines.append(sublist[0])
                else:
                    continue

            if len(chosen_wines) == 1:
                print(chosen_wines[0])
            elif len(chosen_wines) > 1:
                print(random.choice(chosen_wines))
            else:
                print("No wines found")
```

Here's an example of shiraz_list:

```
shiraz_list = [
    ["Wine name 1", "15", "sweet"],
    ["Wine name 2", "15", "sweet"],
    ["Wine name 3", "10", "sweet"],
    ["Wine name 4", "5", "dry"],
    ["Wine name 5", "30", "sour"],
    ["Wine name 6", "20", "sweet"]
]
```

Works just fine. The problem is that I currently have 8 wine kinds (merlot_list, cabernet_list etc), several beer and spirits kinds, and making an "if" condition for each of them doesn't really seem like a very efficient solution.

To solve this, I want to use user's input (interest) to identify which *_list needs to be accessed. I know the following code is unforgivably wrong and will never work, but it would reflect and explain what I'm trying to do here:

```
testlist = interest + "_list"
for sublist in testlist:
    if sublist[1] == budget and sublist[2] == preference:
        chosen_wines.append(sublist[0]) etc...
```

And the question here is: how do I access an existing list depending on customer's input without using a dozen `if`s?

Comment: Nearly always the answer to "how do I turn a string into a variable" is "don't; use a dictionary".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can make a dictionary to match the interest and the lists.

```
# some sample lists
shiraz_list = [["Wine name 1", "15", "sweet"], ["Wine name 2", "15", "sweet"]]
merlot_list = [["Wine name 3", "10", "sweet"], ["Wine name 4", "5", "dry"]]
cabernet_list = [["Wine name 5", "30", "sour"], ["Wine name 6", "20", "sweet"]]

# we can use dictionary to create key:value pairs, then get value by key 
# which is similar to get value by index when using list 
interest_match = {
    "shiraz": shiraz_list,
    "merlot": merlot_list,
    "cabernet": cabernet_list
}

interest = input()

# interest_match[interest] get the list by interest, e.g. interest_match["shiraz"] return shiraz_list 
for sublist in interest_match[interest]:
    print(sublist[0])
```

Output:

```
# Input: shiraz
Wine name 1
Wine name 2
# Input: merlot
Wine name 3
Wine name 4
# Input: cabernet
Wine name 5
Wine name 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an associative array or a key-value system.

```
alcohol = {}
for x in shiraz_list:
   alcohol["shiraz"].push(x)
for x in other_list:
   alcohol["other"].push(x)
```

and so on. Then you can access it like so

```
alcohol[input_variable][iteration]
```